# I'm not able to show registered data

Tags: vue.js

I did a CRUD in vue.js, but it was in cdn, just importing the vue in the file. I want to make this crud work using the vue project. I created this project, installed axios, put the php file that makes the connection and has the create, read, update and delete methods, in xampp.But it doesn't show anything on the page. It has data in the table and shows nothing.

This is the complete component:

```
<template>
   <div class="projects">
      <h1>Projects</h1>

      <div v-for="project in projects" v-bind:key="project.id">
        <p>
         id: {{ project.id }}
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    name: "HelloWorld",
    data() {
      return {
        errorMsg: "",
        successMsg: "",
        projects: [],
        newProject: {
          title: "",
        },
        currentProject: {},
      };
    },
    mounted: function () {
      this.getAllProjects();
    },
    methods: {
      getAllProjects: function () {
        this.axios
          .get("http://localhost/project/action.php?action=read")
          .then(function (response) {
             if (response.data.error) {
               this.errorMsg = response.data.message;
             } else {
               this.projects = response.data.projects;
             }
         });
       },
       addProjects() {
         var formData = this.toFormData(this.newProject);

         this.axios
           .post("http://localhost/project/action.php?action=create", formData)
           .then(function (response) {
             this.newProject = {
               title: "",
             };
           if (response.data.error) {
             this.errorMsg = response.data.message;
           } else {
             this.successMsg = response.data.message;
             this.getAllProjects();
           }
        });
      },
      updateProject() {
        var formData = this.toFormData(this.currentProject);

        this.axios
          .post("http://localhost/project/action.php?action=update", formData)
          .then(function (response) {
            this.currentProject = {};
            if (response.data.error) {
              this.errorMsg = response.data.message;
            } else {
              this.successMsg = response.data.message;
              this.getAllProjects();
            }
          });
      },
      deleteProject() {
        var formData = this.toFormData(this.currentProject);

        this.axios
         .post("http://localhost/project/action.php?action=delete", formData)
         .then(function (response) {
           this.currentProject = {};
           if (response.data.error) {
             this.errorMsg = response.data.message;
           } else {
            this.successMsg = response.data.message;
            this.getAllProjects();
           }
        });
      },
      toFormData(obj) {
        var fd = new FormData();
        for (var i in obj) {
          fd.thisend(i, obj[i]);
        }
        return fd;
      },
      selectUser(project) {
        this.currentProject = project;
      },
    },
  };
</script>
```

Sorry if I didn't leave it well formatted. Please help me, I really need to do this.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you can add this COMPUTED property: (placement: data(){...},computed:{...},methods....)

```
mounted: function () {
  ...
},
computed: {
  projectsList(){
    return this.projects /*your array from data()*/
  }
},
methods: {...
```

And you can try to use `projectsList` in the `v-for`, like `v-for="project in projectsList"`

Comment: It didn't work :(. I put it before, inside and after the methods. I don't know if I did it the right way.

Comment: I edit my answer. And at the beginnig your array is empty `projects: [],`, you are sure to fill it with an `id` ?

Comment: So, I read a lot to get it done and saw everyone doing it that way.
It is empty because in the php file it fills this array with data from the database.

Comment: If I correct understand in `getAllProjects()` you fill your array `projects` with `this.projects = response.data.projects;`. But to use it with the for loop, the array needs to look like `projects = [ { id: 1, ... }, { id: 24, ... },...];`.